# Which assembler should i use to compile this code in dosbox

Tags: assembly, compilation

I have this code to draw a board with 4 rows and 5 columns and fill integer numbers 1-19 in it. How do i compile this using dosbox?
code is in this format:

```
DIM   EQU 9
.MODEL small
.STACK
.DATA
.CODE
.startup

.exit
END
```

Comment: A version of MASM that can output 16-bit code.

Comment: Masm 6.11 (Microsoft 16 bit toolset).